# Can we create a table which Can insert leading Zeros on operation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to insert some data from an excel sheet on to SQL Server 2008 R2. 
Can I Create a table which on insertion of the data can insert leading 0 if the length is less than 5

---

```
   FirstName   Lastname  State  Country  Zip

     XY           z         VA   USA     22031
     AB            Y        MO   USA       423
     Anna         Belle     WA    USA     5234
```

Output:

```
   FirstName   Lastname  State  Country  Zip

     XY           z         VA   USA     22031
     AB            Y        MO   USA     00423
     Anna         Belle     WA    USA    05234
```

Note: The ZIP should still act like an INT

Comment: "The ZIP should still act like an INT" - if that's a real need, store it that way. Pad with leading zeroes at the application level when displaying it. If you store it as a varchar type, you can pad the data with leading zeroes, but you'll have to convert it for use as an int.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7192f89f-e9de-4e9e-a790-d19cbd7a2fd3/i-need-a-zerofill-in-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave the ZIP in the int format, and add the leading zeroes when you select it.  Like this:

```
select right('0000'+convert(varchar(5), ZIP), 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pad the Zip in a varchar field using a pad function like

```
INSERT INTO TableName (FirstName, Lastname, State, Country, Zip)
VALUES ('AB', 'Y', 'MO'. 'USA', REPLACE(STR(423, 5), SPACE(1), '0') )
```

or selecting it formatted if you want to keep the field as INT

```
SELECT FirstName, Lastname, State, Country, REPLACE(STR(zip, 5), SPACE(1), '0') as ZIP
```

Answer (score 2):

If the column is defined as an int, you can't have leading zeros.  You can, however, format the zip to add leading zeros in your queries.  If you store the zip as a varchar you can add the leading zeros and cast the zip to an integer in your queries for comparison purposes if (1) that is what you're after and (2) you aren't using zip codes that have a hyphen.

Example:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE CAST(Zip AS int) BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000
```